# Reply permissions for a Discussion Board in a Site with Read permissions

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, permissions, groups, discussion-board

I currently have a site where all SharePoint groups have Read permissions. However, there is one special group called Discussion Participants that should be able to post and reply to one specific Discussion Board.

The Discussion Participants should not be able to edit other users their posts.

How should I go about this?

- Should I break permission inheriting for the Discussion Board and grant Contributor permissions to the Discussion Participants SharePoint Group?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some time ago I found a great blog article for this and I just dug it out for you.

[This should solve your issues](http://libroarian.wordpress.com/2009/02/09/sharepoint-wss-v3-prevent-users-from-editting-others-discussion-forum-posts/) - How to prevent discussion users from editing each others posts. It's short and sweet and it works.

Comment: Thanks Hugh. This website helped me in setting the Advanced settings: http://referpages.com/wp/2011/03/sp-discussion-board-permissions/